# CheerioJS, looping through <ul> with same class name

Tags: node.js, scrape, cheerio

I'm trying to loop through each `<ul>` and get the value of each `<li>`. The thing is, it only takes the first `<ul>` and skips the rest.

HTML

```
<div id="browse-results">
    <ul class="tips cf">
        <li>tip11</li>
        <li>tip12</li>
        <li>tip13</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="tips cf">
        <li>tip21</li>        
        <li>tip22</li>        
        <li>tip23</li>        
    </ul>
    <ul class="tips cf">
        <li>tip31</li>        
        <li>tip32</li>        
        <li>tip33</li>        
    </ul>
    <ul class="tips cf">
        <li>tip41</li>        
        <li>tip42</li>        
        <li>tip43</li>        
    </ul>
</div>
```

Cheerio Parsing

```
$('#browse-results').find('.tips.cf').each(function(i, elm) {
    console.log($(this).text()) // for testing do text() 
});

$('#browse-results').children().find('.tips').each(function(i, elm) {
    console.log($(this).text())
});
I've tried many more
```

The output is just the values of the first `<ul>`.

```
tip11
tip12
tip13
```

Please note guys that this is just a snippet example with the same structure of what I'm trying to parse.

I spent nearly 2 hours on this, and I can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var html = '<div id="browse-results"> \
    <ul class="tips cf"> \
        <li>tip11</li> \
        <li>tip12</li> \
        <li>tip13</li> \
    </ul> \
    <ul class="tips cf"> \
        <li>tip21</li> \
        <li>tip22</li> \
        <li>tip23</li> \
    </ul> \
    <ul class="tips cf"> \
        <li>tip31</li> \
        <li>tip32</li> \
        <li>tip33</li> \
    </ul> \
    <ul class="tips cf"> \
        <li>tip41</li> \
        <li>tip42</li> \
        <li>tip43</li> \
    </ul> \
</div>';

var $ = cheerio.load(html);

$('#browse-results li').each(function(i, elm) {
    console.log($(this).text()) // for testing do text() 
});
```

This will select all `li` elements which are descendants of `#browse-results`.

Comment: Thanks! Apparently even my code work. But the page I'm trying to scrape for the company it self, is not displaying the whole lists. And I had no idea about that! Spent 3 hours on this. Learned a lesson today :)

Comment: My solution was similar to this. But instead of `console.log($(this).text())` I had to replace it with `console.log($(elm).text())`

Comment: @LewisMenelaws if you were using an arrow function, `this` won't be bound to the current element.

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper selector and iterate over them.

```
for(const element of $("ul.tips.cf li")) {
    console.log($(element).text());
}
```